# Prove formula in Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Prove the following

$$ \vdash A \land (\exists x) (B \rightarrow C) \equiv (\exists x)(B \rightarrow (A \land C)) $$

as long as $ x$ not free in $A$.

This is question number 9 chapter 6 in "Mathematical Logic" by Tourlakis. How could i prove it ?

Comment: Do you know how to use analytic tableaux?

Comment: I don't know what is that. I need to proof it by the system the book works with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you must follow the Hint in Ex.9, page 187 : "Translate first to standard notation."

The formulae are written with *bounded quantifiers*, following Bourbaki's style :

> $\vdash A \land (\exists x)_B C \equiv (\exists x)_B (A \land C)$, as long as $x$ not free in $A$.

The formula with the bounded quantifier $(\exists x)_B$ must be rewritten [see page 175] as :

> > $A \land (\exists x) (B \land C)$;

due to the fact that $x$ is not free in $A$, we may apply **Corollary 6.4.3** [page 174] : $\vdash (\exists x)(A \land B) \equiv A \land (\exists x) B$, to get :

> $(\exists x)[A \land (B \land C)]$.

Now, we "rearrange" the *conjuncts* [see **Ex 2.4.22**, page 74 : $\vdash A \land (B \land C) \equiv (A \land B) \land C$ and $\vdash A \land B \equiv B \land A$ --- use *Leibniz*] to have :

> $(\exists x)[B \land (A \land C)]$,

and this is (in *bounded quantifier* form) :

> > $(\exists x)_B (A \land C)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Which Leibniz should i use, Strong or Weak ?

Comment: @Tennisman - the formal details of the proof are obviously the same of **6.4.3 Corollary** : $\vdash (\exists x)(A \land B) \equiv A \land (\exists x) B$, provided $x$ is not free in $A$ , page 174. We only need an additional "intermediate" step to "rearrange" the conjuncts. As you can see from the proof, we need both **WL** and **SL** (see page 166).